# Calling a Rake task from a controller with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a instance variable in my controller that queries my table for a value, and I need to send that value through to my rake task.

So here are the 2 relevant lines in my controller:

```
 @turl = Fteam.where(:id => @ids).select(:TeamUrl)
system "rake updateTm:update[@turl]"
```

Here is my rake file:

```
desc "Import Players"
  task :update, [:Tmurl] => :environment do |t, args|

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

puts "This is the selected Team URL: #{args.Tmurl}"
  end
end
```

This is what the rake task returns:

```
This is the selected Team URL: @turl
```

My guess is that the controller is not passing the variable correctly. So how can I pass the actual value of the variable to the rake task so the output is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you may need to use interpolation

```
"rake updateTm:update[#{@turl}]"
```

Comment: This errored it said: rake filename directory or volume label syntax

Answer (score 0):

It is a .rb file. and and in ruby we can'y call variable directly.

You should use

```
system "rake updateTm:update[#{@turl}]"
```

Comment: filename directory or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Your rake task is calling from controller by this way ? Did you debug that ?

Comment: Yes, but i noticed that it was not giving the actual value and i have come up with an answer, which i will be posting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help and ideas everyone, i came up with a solution.

Instead of `@turl = Fteam.where(:id => @ids).select(:TeamUrl)` 
I changed that to `@turl = Fteam.where(:id => @ids).pluck(:TeamUrl)`

That gave me the actual value that i needed rather then the active record, which was causing the error because it could not pass a value for which it could not translate or understand.